# Sending SQL Queries to CSV file on Excel VBA doesn't work for Date Columns

Tags: excel, vba, ado, adodb, import-from-csv

I am trying to get some data from a csv file having more than than 3 million rows. I've set an ADODB connection to my csv file and everything works fine except for querying date columns.

Here is how I set the connection

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

With conn
   .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0"
   .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & fileDirPath & ";Extended Properties='text'"
End With

conn.Open
```

The query I send is

```
SELECT * FROM my_csv.csv WHERE myDate < 2030-12-01
```

Although all the dates in myDate column are smaller than 2030-12-01, recordset returns an empty result. It's not spesific for that date, any query with myDate column returns empty. Thanks a lot in advance for your support.

My schema.ini file looks like

```
[my_csv.csv]
DecimalSymbol=.
Format=CSVDelimited
ColNameHeader=True
DateTimeFormat=YYYY-MM-DD
DecimalSymbol=,
Col1=org_id Text 
Col2=app_id Text 
Col3=myDate Date(YYYY-MM-DD)
Col4=valid Text
```

Here is how my data is formatted

```
cpt_id,rmn_id,myDate,valid
1285230,652671575,2019-03-12,true
1956123,1384198347,2019-03-15,true
2123640,1901167025,2019-02-21,true
2231241,1021153291,2019-03-02,true
7349946,1462824644,2019-03-07,true
7349946,4661867294,2019-03-16,true
1956123,3611518899,2019-03-01,true
```

Comment: single quotes around the date literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it seems that the date specified in the query needs quotes around it to prevent the data from being a subtraction problem.  Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_csv.csv WHERE myDate < '2030-12-01'
```

I haven't worked much with the ACE database driver, if it is like the older JET, it may require pound signs (#) for date literals, so if the above does not work, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_csv.csv WHERE myDate < #2030-12-01#
```

Comment: Pound signs are what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!